# Windows 8 with multiple screens: Main screen does not wake up

Tags: windows-8, sleep, hybrid-sleep

I am having an issue like few others with computer not waking up from sleep.

However I noticed slight difference, I run 2 screens and when I move the mouse or press something on the keyboard, 2nd screen activates just fine. Basically with 2 screens running, it is visible that my computer wakes up normally but main screen just doesnt turn on, as i can browse internet and run programs in the 2nd screen. I basically have to use power options to restart or something similar to wake up the second screen.

When I say it doesnt turn on, I mean its not just black or screen saver, it looks like there is no power to it at all

Screen 1, laptop screen on Inspiron 15R

Screen 2, Dell monitor

When I try to identify monitors, it recognizes that laptop has 2. Second screen flashes "2" and 1st is properly described in the properties. Yet, it is completely turned off

Comment: Can you check if it's detected in the display screen (Control Panel, Diosplay, Adjust Resolution)

Comment: Right now it is, it is bit hard to replicate the issue as I am away from second screen right now (laptop). Will try to detect it next time.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain exactly what type of monitors are in question (so we know what 'screen 1' and 'screen 2' actually are), and how they're attached.

Comment: @techie007 they are attached with a cable... not the s-video or analog, normal monitor cable

Comment: I have the same issue albeit in Linux - removing the hdmi cable wakes up the primary screen, then I re-insert the hdmi to wake the 2nd.  Same process might work in Wind0ze? (horrible work-around until proper fix is available...)